# How to pass a data-title from a page to a fancybox form element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have se a jsfiddle to help you to understand my goal

http://jsfiddle.net/CE2MZ/1/

What I am trying to do is to pass a php variable from my page to a fancybox form through data-title.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".modalbox").fancybox({
        'closeBtn' : false
        });

     $(".action-xam").click(function(){
    //Get some info like the title
    var title = $(this).next("div").data("title");
    //Insert the info into xam
    $("#krimmeno").val(title);
});


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you want but if you replace the `.next` by `.find("div:first-child")` it will select the first `div` in your `link` or you can target the class `.find(".service-box")`.

The `.next` is for sibling elements.

```
var title = $(this).find("div:first-child").data("title");
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CE2MZ/3/)